# How to auto generate permalink from meta data?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

After searching on stackoverflow.com for hours, I just can't find any answers.

Can someone help me out in the right direction?

So, what i'm trying to achieve is the following...

I would like to have the postname and the permalink to be autogenerated for single posts via

```
$post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $attachment_title
```

Either pull the data from the image_alt or the attachment_title and set as postname and permalink...

```
add_action('save_post', 'set_slug');

    function set_slug($attachment_id){
        $new_slug = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_title,'_wp_attachment_image_alt',  true); 
        $post_args = array(
            'ID' => $attachment_id,
            'post_name' => $new_slug,
        );

        wp_update_post($post_args);
    }
```

I tried serval codes in my functions.php to alter single post permalinks, but so far without success.

Answer (score 0):

wp_update_post() returns an int the post ID on success and WP_Error on failure. What is the return value of your call to wp_update_post()?

But, I suspect this may result in an infinite recursion as wp_update_post() calls wp_insert_post() which does do_action( 'save_post', ... ) . In this you will get the PHP error time limit exceeded - and the call to wp_update_post() never returns.

You may be better off using the filter 'wp_insert_attachment_data' which is called with arguments $data and $postarr and modifying the 'post_name' in $data.

Comment: Thank you @magenta. I will definitely try out what you recommend, hopefully soon with success :)